# Linux Last command weird output? Garbage for IP address

Tags: last

This was a weird output I came across. Running the "last" command gave me this output

```
gryphon  pts/0        192.168.0.108    Wed Mar 19 21:04   still logged in
gryphon  pts/0        s0106d850e695678 Wed Mar 19 13:53 - 13:54  (00:01)
gryphon  pts/0        192.168.0.108    Tue Mar 18 22:57 - 23:03  (00:06)
```

I'm pretty sure that the weird IP address was me but what is up with the garbage for the IP address?

I do not have an IPV6 address. It's just a weird hostname I don't have anything named that. I might have been VPN'ing in would that have anything to do with it?

Comment: Do you have an [ipv6 address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address)?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch doesn't look like a v6 address to me. you'd see more `::`s and `:`s.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As **Ricky Beam** mentioned, it is a hostname, but sadly, it was too long and therefore cut off. If you want to display the *entire* host name without any trimming, run the command with the `-F` flag (capitalization matters).

```
$ last
andreas  pts/15       123-27-247-110.c Fri Jun 13 00:24 - 00:33  (00:08)    
$ last -w -F
andreas  pts/15       123-27-247-110.client.mchsi.com Fri Jun 13 00:24:24 2014 - Fri Jun 13 00:33:03 2014  (00:08)
```

Comment: The related `-w` flag also used in the example displays the full date, not just a "minimal" version.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an address. It's a hostname. (or as much of it as will fit in a wtmp entry.)